# Structure packing duplicity

Tags: c++, structure, memory-alignment, preprocessor-directive, compiler-options

I am writing code to [a specification](http://www.asprs.org/a/society/committees/standards/LAS_1_4_r13.pdf) which defines structures without packing, for example:

```
struct LASHeader_1p2
{
    char FileSig[4]; //= "LASF";                    // 4
    unsigned __int16 FileSource;                    // 2   6
    unsigned __int16 Reserved_Unused;               // 2   8
    unsigned __int32 Project_ID_Data1;              // 4  12
    unsigned __int16 Project_ID_Data2;              // 2  14
    unsigned __int16 Project_ID_Data3;              // 2  16
    char Project_ID_Data4[8];                       // 8  24
    unsigned char Version_Major;                    // 1  25
    unsigned char Version_Minor;                    // 1  26
    char System_ID[32];                             //32  58
    char Software[32];                              //32  90
    unsigned __int16 FC_Day, FC_Year, Header_Size;  // 2,2,2 96
    unsigned __int32 Offset_to_Data;                // 4 100 0x60
    unsigned __int32 VarLenRecs;                    // 4 104 0x64
    unsigned char Pt_DataFormat;                    // 1 105 0x65
    unsigned __int16 Pt_DataRecLen;                 // 2 107 0x68
    unsigned __int32 PointCount;                    // 4 111 0x6A
    unsigned __int32 Point_by_Return_0;             // 4 115
    unsigned __int32 Point_by_Return_1;             // 4 119
    unsigned __int32 Point_by_Return_2;             // 4 123
    unsigned __int32 Point_by_Return_3;             // 4 127
    unsigned __int32 Point_by_Return_4;             // 4 131
    double Xscale;                                  // 8 139
    double Yscale;                                  // 8 147
    double Zscale;                                  // 8 155
    double Xoffset;                                 // 8 163
    double Yoffset;                                 // 8 171
    double Zoffset;                                 // 8 179
    double MaxX;                                    // 8 187
    double MinX;                                    // 8 195
    double MaxY;                                    // 8 203
    double MinY;                                    // 8 211
    double MaxZ;                                    // 8 219
    double MinZ;                                    // 8 227
};
```

Around `unsigned char Pt_DataFormat;` the structure gets out of alignment against the default (4 byte). To compensate for this I use /Zp1 compiler option to use the structure with no padding/alignment. Although potentially slower this allows me to read the bytes and interpret as a structure:

```
char* buffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(LASHeader_1p2));
pReadStream.read(buffer ,sizeof(LASHeader_1p2));
LASHeader_1p2* Header = (LASHeader_1p2*)buffer;
```

Which I can modify values and then write to a file as bytes. The only other option is to break the structure into sections that will align and read that individual byte, which seems kind of dodgy to me.

However other libraries don't like /Zp1, I suspect they contain internally padded structures which no longer operate when unpadded.

I have been looking at [pragma pack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1.aspx) and [__declspec(align())](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/71kf49f1(v=vs.100).aspx) but am not sure of which would be suitable and how to use them.

Can anyone shed light on how to proceed, to read and cast the structure without padding but maintain the padding for other libraries that require it?

Comment: Depends on which compiler you're using, but generally all of them supply a way to push the current packing value, change it for some amount of code, then pop back to whatever it was before.

Comment: I'm using visual studio 2010, C++. Does the #pragma go in the header with the declaration of the structure or around the code that's using it? what do I use when I'm finished that bit and want it set back to default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Visual Studio you'd want to surround your struct with:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1) //Save packing value and set to 1 byte
<struct definition>
#pragma pack(pop)  //Reset to whatever the packing was before.
```

So, this:

```
#include <iostream>

#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct packed
{
    char FileSig[4]; //= "LASF";                    // 4
    unsigned __int16 FileSource;                    // 2   6
    unsigned __int16 Reserved_Unused;               // 2   8
    unsigned __int32 Project_ID_Data1;              // 4  12
    unsigned __int16 Project_ID_Data2;              // 2  14
    unsigned __int16 Project_ID_Data3;              // 2  16
    char Project_ID_Data4[8];                       // 8  24
    unsigned char Version_Major;                    // 1  25
    unsigned char Version_Minor;                    // 1  26
    char System_ID[32];                             //32  58
    char Software[32];                              //32  90
    unsigned __int16 FC_Day, FC_Year, Header_Size;  // 2,2,2 96
    unsigned __int32 Offset_to_Data;                // 4 100 0x60
    unsigned __int32 VarLenRecs;                    // 4 104 0x64
    unsigned char Pt_DataFormat;                    // 1 105 0x65
    unsigned __int16 Pt_DataRecLen;                 // 2 107 0x68
    unsigned __int32 PointCount;                    // 4 111 0x6A
    unsigned __int32 Point_by_Return_0;             // 4 115
    unsigned __int32 Point_by_Return_1;             // 4 119
    unsigned __int32 Point_by_Return_2;             // 4 123
    unsigned __int32 Point_by_Return_3;             // 4 127
    unsigned __int32 Point_by_Return_4;             // 4 131
    double Xscale;                                  // 8 139
    double Yscale;                                  // 8 147
    double Zscale;                                  // 8 155
    double Xoffset;                                 // 8 163
    double Yoffset;                                 // 8 171
    double Zoffset;                                 // 8 179
    double MaxX;                                    // 8 187
    double MinX;                                    // 8 195
    double MaxY;                                    // 8 203
    double MinY;                                    // 8 211
    double MaxZ;                                    // 8 219
    double MinZ;                                    // 8 227
};
#pragma pack(pop)

struct unpacked
{
    char FileSig[4]; //= "LASF";                    // 4
    unsigned __int16 FileSource;                    // 2   6
    unsigned __int16 Reserved_Unused;               // 2   8
    unsigned __int32 Project_ID_Data1;              // 4  12
    unsigned __int16 Project_ID_Data2;              // 2  14
    unsigned __int16 Project_ID_Data3;              // 2  16
    char Project_ID_Data4[8];                       // 8  24
    unsigned char Version_Major;                    // 1  25
    unsigned char Version_Minor;                    // 1  26
    char System_ID[32];                             //32  58
    char Software[32];                              //32  90
    unsigned __int16 FC_Day, FC_Year, Header_Size;  // 2,2,2 96
    unsigned __int32 Offset_to_Data;                // 4 100 0x60
    unsigned __int32 VarLenRecs;                    // 4 104 0x64
    unsigned char Pt_DataFormat;                    // 1 105 0x65
    unsigned __int16 Pt_DataRecLen;                 // 2 107 0x68
    unsigned __int32 PointCount;                    // 4 111 0x6A
    unsigned __int32 Point_by_Return_0;             // 4 115
    unsigned __int32 Point_by_Return_1;             // 4 119
    unsigned __int32 Point_by_Return_2;             // 4 123
    unsigned __int32 Point_by_Return_3;             // 4 127
    unsigned __int32 Point_by_Return_4;             // 4 131
    double Xscale;                                  // 8 139
    double Yscale;                                  // 8 147
    double Zscale;                                  // 8 155
    double Xoffset;                                 // 8 163
    double Yoffset;                                 // 8 171
    double Zoffset;                                 // 8 179
    double MaxX;                                    // 8 187
    double MinX;                                    // 8 195
    double MaxY;                                    // 8 203
    double MinY;                                    // 8 211
    double MaxZ;                                    // 8 219
    double MinZ;                                    // 8 227
};


int main()
{
    std::cout << "sizeof(packed)   = " << sizeof(packed) << "\n";
    std::cout << "sizeof(unpacked) = " << sizeof(unpacked) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

outputs

```
sizeof(packed)   = 227
sizeof(unpacked) = 232
```

You can even nest them and give different levels names if you like, but I've rarely had to do so.  The documentation is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28pack_CPP%29%3Bk%28pack%29%3Bk%28DevLang-C%2B%2B%29%3Bk%28TargetOS-Windows%29&rd=true).

Comment: Thank you, I was fairly sure I had the right tool just didn't know where to apply it, that clears it up nicely for me. Now I can use #pragma pack in the header containing the struct and compile to default structure packing - allowing the external library to run properly and also dynamically casting the structure properly.